# Confirmation PopUp( Yes or No) in Spring MVC Servlet Response Object and Handle Yes and No events

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working in a spring mvc servlet project.
I have a form where there are 2 dropdowns

Suppose a) Month : b) Year :

and one Submit button.

Now when **user selects value in both dropdown and click on Submit** : The control goes to the onSubmit function of **Controller GenerateForm**. 
Here I do a database query and suppose that query gives me a value which I store in variable x.
Now

```
if (x>0){
    give a confirmation popup in UI ASKING user ->
    Do you want to continue ?
    if( userClicks Yes){
    delete database value
    continue with normal flow ;
    }else{
        return null ;
    }
}
else{
    continue with normal flow ;
    save into database
}
```

Please help me **how should I create this confirmation popup ? The control is in the Controller at this point.** Please see the code skeleton below.

**Code Skeleton :**

**Model Class :**

```
public class Report {
    private String month;
    private String year;
    //getter setter here
}
```

**Controller Class :**

```
public class GenerateForm extends BaseFormController {

    // declaration of other class objects here

    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        // assert calls here 
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
    }

    protected Object formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

        Report rp = (Report)createCommand();
        return rp;
    }

    protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object command,   BindException errors)
                throws Exception { 
        Report rp = (Report) command;

        x = Call_to_Manager_Class(rp); // Manager class in turn call DAO class

        if (x>0){
            give a confirmation popup in UI ASKING user ->
            Do you want to continue ?
            if( userClicks Yes){
                continue with normal flow ;
                return new ModelAndView(getSuccessView());
            }else{
                return null ; // stay on same page
            }
        }
        else{
            continue with normal flow ;
            return new ModelAndView(getSuccessView());
        }   

    }

    protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request,
            ServletRequestDataBinder binder) throws Exception {

        // binding done here
    }

    protected Map referenceData(HttpServletRequest request, Object command,
            Errors errors) throws Exception {
        //code related to reference data here   
        return data;
    }

}
```

**.xml file**

```
<bean id="generatForm" class="com.web.controller.GenerateForm">
    <property name="commandName" value="generate" />
    <property name="commandClass" value="com.domain.Report" />
    formview,success view and cancel view defined here similarly
</bean>
```

All beans are defined properly. The control is going to the onSubmit function. Now help me **how can I generate that confirmation popup in UI asking user to Press Yes or No and handling it accordingly**.

**EDIT** :
I did the following change as suggested But the form is also getting submitted along with the Ajax request although I am getting the ajax response properly and also the confirmation popUp. How to prevent the form from getting submitted and I want it to submit only when user press Ok in the confirmation popup.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#myForm').submit(function (ev) {
        console.log(1);
        var year = $('#year').val();
        var month = $('#month').val();
        console.log(year);
        console.log(month);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'ActionServlet',
            data: "year=" + year + "&month=" + month,
            success: function (data) {
              console.log(data);
              $('#ajaxDiv').text(data);
              var result= parseInt(data, 10);
              if (result > 0) {
                    if(!confirm("you sure about that?")){
                        ev.preventDefault(); 
                    }
              }
            },error : function(e) {
                alert('Error: ' + e); 
            }
        });  
});
});
```

**EDIT 2**
Even if I write e.preventDefault() at the start, the AJAX call will still be asynchronous and by the time the ajax response arrives this function flow will end. I tried doing that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myForm').submit(function (ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            console.log(1);
            var year = $('#year').val();
            var month = $('#month').val();
            console.log(year);
            console.log(month);
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'ActionServlet',
                data: "year=" + year + "&month=" + month,
                success: function (data) {
                  console.log(data);
                  $('#ajaxDiv').text(data);
                  var result= parseInt(data, 10);
                  if (result > 0) {
                        if(confirm("you sure about that?")){
                            //$('form').unbind('submit').submit();
                            $('#myForm').submit();
                            //$(this).unbind('submit').submit();
                            //$('#submit').click();
                            //$(this).trigger(submit); 
                            //$(this).submit();
                        }
                  }
                },error : function(e) {
                    alert('Error: ' + e); 
                }
            }); 
           console.log(2); 
    });
    });
```

But once the form is prevented from submitting by ev.preventDefault(), I am not able to submit it again on the basis of my Confirm Popup. I have tried many ways. If I remove my Ajax Call

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myForm').submit(function (ev) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                console.log(1);
                var year = $('#year').val();
                var month = $('#month').val();
                console.log(year);
                console.log(month);
                $(this).submit();
                console.log(2); 
        });
        });
```

It goes into a recursive call. I can stop that recursion using some variable but If I put this inside confirm , It doesn't call submit event again.

```
<div id="pageButtons">
    <button name="_submit" id="submit" > Generate</button>
</div>
```

This is my submit button configuration.
Please help me fix this last issue.

**EDIT 3**:

I tried the last code suggestion and It gave me this console :

```
Uncaught TypeError: form.submit is not a function !!
```

Then FOR the **submit button** I removed the id="submit". After then when I re-run my code, **as soon as I hit the Submit button, my form gets submitted and this jQuery event is also fired**. The confirmation Popup comes, if I select Ok , the form is again submitted. So **Why is the form getting submitted automatically ? Before user clicks OK in confirmation popup ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can introduce javascript to do so. I'll use jQuery for demo:

```
$("#your-form").submit(function(e) {
    if(!confirm("you sure about that?")){
         e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

A popup dialog will popup when submit button is clicked. This will prevent the form from submitting to controller if the user does not want to submit.

**Update per OP's comment:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#myForm').submit(function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault(); // prevent default action witch is form-submit
    var form = this; // avoid using jQuery's selection. 
    console.log(1);
    var year = $('#year').val();
    var month = $('#month').val();
    console.log(year);
    console.log(month);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'ActionServlet',
        data: "year=" + year + "&month=" + month,
        success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
          $('#ajaxDiv').text(data);
          var result= parseInt(data, 10);
          if (result > 0) {
                if(confirm("you sure about that?")){ //if yes is clicked (negation is removed) 
                    form.submit(); // this won't trigger the jQuery's submission, so it will not cause infinite loop.
                }
          }
        },error : function(e) {
            alert('Error: ' + e); 
        }
    });  
});
});
```

Comment: According to your solution, the popup will  come before the form is submitted. But I want to do a database query also before giving the popup.    IF the result of query is greater than zero value, then Only i want to generate the popup. Please read my question again and help me figure out how to do the query based on user selected values and then give popup. thanks

Comment: @IshantSharma you can just add an AJAX call to get the result and do w/e with the result. I also updated my solution.

Comment: I changed my code as you suggested. But when i am sending the ajax call to get the result, my form is also getting submitted at the same time. The ajax response is okay and confirmation popup is also generated. But the submission of form is independent of pop up option.

Comment: I have updated my Question with the code of Ajax . Please see the Edit  Section in the question.

Comment: @IshantSharma This happens when because of the async nature of ajax call. When $.ajax is called, the statements after will be called at the same time, hense the submission of the form. Please see update.

Comment: I have editted my question again. Please see Edit 2. Help me fix this last issue. I am not able to submit form once i prevent it from submitting. Thanks in advance

Comment: @IshantSharma I am sorry I did not test my code and assumed it worked perfectly, I have tested and updated my answer this time and it worked on my machine.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: form.submit is not a function !!

Comment: Still no Luck for me !! If I put a console.log() statement after $.ajax({}) call then that comes in console before my ajax response data is returned. Can you show me for button submit what id and name you have used. Does that also effect this.

Comment: See Edit 3 in Question . Help :(

Comment: Hi Minjun.. !! Thanks a lot for the help. My issue got resolved. I will update in the Question how it got resolved. But finally the solution that you have given is complete and absolutely right !